# Error "core dumped" after operator reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>

Tags: java, c++, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, coredump

I have the following problem:

I've created Java project, which uses C++ dynamic library through JNI. It reads images and analizes it characteristics.  When I run **C++ project**, which uses the same library - everything is **fine** and process terminates without errors, but **Java project** terminates on different images  with **error** "The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. ...core dumped".

The piece of code that causes the error is the following:

```
vector<char> getFileContent(const string &fileName)
{
    ifstream file(fileName.c_str());
    vector<char> buf;
    copy( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),std::back_inserter(buf) );
    return buf;
} 

int analyzeFiles(vector<File> files)
{
    //check for extension ". jpg"
    for(size_t i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    {   
        vector<char> fileContent = getFileContent(files[i].directory + '/' + files[i].fileName);
        DrawingDetector dd(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&fileContent[0]), fileContent.size()); //causes error in a runtime, terminates on any image
        //the rest code
    }
}
```

Has anyone any ideas? I will be grateful for any advice on the subject of my question.

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the case where the vector is empty(`&fileContent[0]` could be invalid at this point.)

A quick check would be to see if the file really was opened.